# Операции приведения типов С++

Tags: c++, классы, битовые-операции, преобразование-типов

Всем привет. Изучая книгу Бьярне Страуструпа, я наткнулся на интересный, по моему мнению, пример:

```
class Tiny {
 char v;
 void assign(int i) { 
  if(i&~077)               // #1
   throw Bad_range();
  v = i;
 }

public:
 class Bad_range{};

 Tiny(int i) { assign(i); }
 Tiny& operator = (int i) { assign(i); return *this; }

 operator int() const { return v; }
};


int main () {
 Tiny c1 = 2;
 Tiny c2 = 1;
 Tiny c3 = c1 - c2;       // #2
}
```

Так вот, первый вопрос(# 1), что это за условие, так как я вижу его впервые.
И (# 2), выражение (`c1 - c2`) превратится в тип `int` или `Tiny`? И будет ли разница в производительности, если не учитывать второй вопрос?

Comment: для двух разных вопросов(не связанных между собой) лучше создать два отдельных вопроса на StackOverflow. а Ваши Вопросы насколько я вижу не зависят друг от друга.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

077 - число в восьмеричной системе счисления, которое бинарно записывается как 00..00111111 - нули до размера `int`. Операция `~` обращает все биты, т.е. получается 11..11000000. Операция побитового И с таким числом даст `true` (ненулевое значение) при наличии в числе хотя бы одного единичного бита начиная с 6 (считая от нуля). Так что это проверка, что число от 0 до 63 включительно (как для беззнаковых, так и для знаковых чисел), вернее, что число вне этого диапазона - тогда генерируется исключение.

Во второй части `c1` и `c2` для разности будут приведены к типу `int` (оператор `int()`), и результат вычитания типа `int` будет использован для создания объекта `c3` типа `Tiny` (конструктор `Tiny(int)`).